# Remove stopwords Tweets using Python

Tags: python, twitter, stop-words

I have a large txt file, consisting of Tweets separated per line.
Now I want to remove stopwords such as 'the', 'to' etc. out of these messages, and get a new textfile with the same tweets but with stopwords removed.

What's going wrong in the code below?

Thanks!

```
import re, string

#this code removes stopwords
input_file = 'enneg2.txt'
output_file = 'enneg3.txt'

stoplist = set('for a of the and to in'.split())
table = string.maketrans("","")

with open(input_file) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()


for line in lines:
    filtered_line = [w for w in line.split() if not w in stoplist]
    with open(output_file, 'a') as myfile:
        myfile.write(filtered_line)
```

I receive error message: Traceback (most recent call last): File "delstopwords.py", line 19, in  myfile.write(filtered_line) TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: *"What's going wrong in the code below?"* I don't know, you tell us! Are you getting an error? Is it producing incorrect results?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you shouldn't call `readlines`. The `file` object returned by `open` is iterable by lines already and doesn't require reading the entire file into memory in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a `.split()` is missing, it should be written like this. And filtered_line is a list you need to transform it back into a string to save it in a file.

```
filtered_line = [w for w in line.split() if not w in stoplist]
filtered_line=' '.join(filtered_line)+'\n'
myfile.write(filtered_line)
```

Comment: Sorry, even after using your adjustment I still receive error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "delstopwords.py", line 19, in <module>
    myfile.write(filtered_line)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: It seems to remove the stopwords, thanks! But now I see all Tweets behind each other (without any separation).

So
Before running:

I am the chicken
You go to prison

After running current script:

I am chickenYou go prison

Where I desire:

I am chicken
You go prison

So still would like to see the lines separated.

Comment: @mvh just add the newline character to the end of the filtered_line. see the updated answer